# Android Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) - ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@

Tags: android, azure, android-activity, sdk, adal

I am fairly new to android/java.  I am trying to incorporate the example code for ADAL into my app, but when I call mAuthContext.aquireToken(), login prompt does not appear and I see errors in logcat about no activity for token.  Is my activity getting destroyed for some reason?

I've searched but I'm not finding others that have this same kind of problem.  I have a feeling I modified some code that is causing this and I cannot find what it is.  I have tried different ways of referencing the activity in the first param of mAuthContext.acquireToken() but I don't think that is the problem.  Any help is MUCH appreciated!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.kclogo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    signOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signoutButton);
    signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSignOutClicked();
        }
    });
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onScanClicked();
        }
    });

    mAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, false);

    /* Instantiate handler which can invoke interactive sign-in to get the Resource
     * sIntSignInInvoked ensures interactive sign-in is invoked one at a time */

    mAcquireTokenHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (sIntSignInInvoked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                try {
                    if (msg.what == MSG_INTERACTIVE_SIGN_IN_PROMPT_AUTO) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "$$$ Launching - MSG_INTERACTIVE_SIGN_IN_PROMPT_AUTO");
                        mAuthContext.acquireToken(getActivity(), RESOURCE_ID, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, PromptBehavior.Auto, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
                    } else if (msg.what == MSG_INTERACTIVE_SIGN_IN_PROMPT_ALWAYS) {
                        mAuthContext.acquireToken(getActivity(), RESOURCE_ID, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, PromptBehavior.Always, getAuthInteractiveCallback());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    /* ADAL Logging callback setup */

    Logger.getInstance().setExternalLogger(new Logger.ILogger() {
        @Override
        public void Log(String tag, String message, String additionalMessage, Logger.LogLevel level, ADALError errorCode) {
            // You can filter the logs  depending on level or errorcode.
            Log.d(TAG, message + " " + additionalMessage);
        }
    });

    /*Attempt an acquireTokenSilent call to see if we're signed in*/
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String userId = preferences.getString(USER_ID, "");
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Silent");
        mAuthContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(RESOURCE_ID, CLIENT_ID, userId, getAuthSilentCallback());
    }
}



private void onScanClicked() {
    mAcquireTokenHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_INTERACTIVE_SIGN_IN_PROMPT_AUTO);

}
```

LOGCAT:
2018-12-19 14:07:06.702 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/MainActivity: $$$ Launching - MSG_INTERACTIVE_SIGN_IN_PROMPT_AUTO
2018-12-19 14:07:06.716 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Sending async task from thread:15061 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.724 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Running task in thread:15097 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.731 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Broker auth is turned off or no valid broker is available on the device, cannot switch to broker. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.736 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Try to acquire token silently, return valid AT or use RT in the cache. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.742 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Try to silently get token from local cache. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.759 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-No access token exists. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.764 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-No valid access token exists, try with refresh token. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.785 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Regular token cache entry does not exist, try with MRRT. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.800 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-MRRT token does not exist, try with FRT ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.807 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-FRT cache item does not exist, fall back to try MRRT. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.811 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Send request to use MRRT for new AT. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.816 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-MRRT does not exist, cannot proceed with MRRT for new AT. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.822 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Broker auth is turned off or no valid broker is available on the device, cannot switch to broker. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.830 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Put waiting request. requestId:93475433  CorrelationId: 56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.837 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Broker auth is turned off or no valid broker is available on the device, cannot switch to broker. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.843 15061-15097/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:06-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Starting Authentication Activity for embedded flow.  ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:06.880 1918-2527/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity (has extras)} from uid 10092
2018-12-19 14:07:06.893 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1194
2018-12-19 14:07:06.901 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ff0f877
2018-12-19 14:07:06.913 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Activity paused, time: 49751619
2018-12-19 14:07:06.926 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: onActivityCreated
2018-12-19 14:07:06.939 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1194, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345432}]
2018-12-19 14:07:07.049 2743-15104/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.solvednetworks.cptool', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1194, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345432}]}
2018-12-19 14:07:07.055 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 66.0.3359.158 (code 336015817)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.061 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/networks.cptoo: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2018-12-19 14:07:07.100 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 5 ms (timestamps 1821-1826)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.151 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2018-12-19 14:07:07.152 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "66.0.3359.158", actual native library version number "66.0.3359.158"
2018-12-19 14:07:07.187 15061-15110/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
2018-12-19 14:07:07.222 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
2018-12-19 14:07:07.224 1918-1946/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 15112:com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0/u0i12 for webview_service com.solvednetworks.cptool/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0
2018-12-19 14:07:07.225 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/cr_base: Android Locale: en_US requires .pak files: [en-GB.pak, en-US.pak]
2018-12-19 14:07:07.337 15061-15141/com.solvednetworks.cptool E/chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(292)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.
2018-12-19 14:07:07.427 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.427 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.427 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.428 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.428 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.428 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.428 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.428 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.458 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-AuthenticationActivity was created. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.515 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Init broadcastReceiver with request. RequestId:93475433 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.524 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9- ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.530 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Non-broker request for package com.solvednetworks.cptool ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.536 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Device info:9 GoogleAndroid SDK built for x86 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.561 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Correlation id for request sent is:56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.618 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2466986703034345432, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345433}]
2018-12-19 14:07:07.732 2743-15104/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.solvednetworks.cptool', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2466986703034345432, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345433}]}
2018-12-19 14:07:07.732 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 49752310
2018-12-19 14:07:07.851 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:07-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Launching webview for acquiring auth code. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:07.873 15061-15131/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2018-12-19 14:07:07.885 15061-15098/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2bcfa40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd25ec380)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.929 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xc92a7860: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2018-12-19 14:07:07.929 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xc92a7860: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7d922e0)
2018-12-19 14:07:07.936 1918-1954/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity: +1s23ms
2018-12-19 14:07:08.062 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 4 for video/hevc
2018-12-19 14:07:08.119 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Webview starts loading.  ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.130 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2018-12-19 14:07:08.133 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-DisplaySpinner:true showing:false ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.170 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
2018-12-19 14:07:08.185 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeccc3160: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2018-12-19 14:07:08.185 15061-15150/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeccc3160: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7d922e0)
2018-12-19 14:07:08.504 1754-1754/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity to com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity#1
2018-12-19 14:07:08.597 15061-15098/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2bcfa40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd25ec380)
2018-12-19 14:07:08.728 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Navigation is detected ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.737 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Navigation starts with the redirect uri. ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.752 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-It is not a broker request ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.759 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Return To Caller:2003 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.767 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-DisplaySpinner:false showing:true ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.781 15061-15098/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2bcfa40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd25ec380)
2018-12-19 14:07:08.792 1754-1754/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing Surface(name=cf5a7cb com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity)/@0x60bde66 - animation-leash to Surface(name=cf5a7cb com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity)/@0x60bde66 - animation-leash#1
2018-12-19 14:07:08.802 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Set request id related to response. REQUEST_ID for caller returned to:93475433 ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.830 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-AuthenticationActivity onPause unregister receiver ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.833 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1250
2018-12-19 14:07:08.835 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/MainActivity: 2018-12-19 21:07:08-56b96149-f5c0-41d6-8195-baac64ea35a9-Spinner at onPause will dismiss ver:1.14.1 null
2018-12-19 14:07:08.844 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Activity paused, time: 49753559
2018-12-19 14:07:08.875 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1250, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345433}]
2018-12-19 14:07:08.974 15061-15061/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2018-12-19 14:07:08.987 1754-1940/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity#1
2018-12-19 14:07:08.987 1754-1940/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: com.solvednetworks.cptool/com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity#1
2018-12-19 14:07:08.987 2743-15104/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.solvednetworks.cptool', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1250, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345433}]}
2018-12-19 14:07:08.989 15061-15098/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2bcfa40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd25ec380)
2018-12-19 14:07:09.032 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2466986703034345433, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345432}]
2018-12-19 14:07:09.123 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 49753582
2018-12-19 14:07:09.128 2743-15104/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.solvednetworks.cptool', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=AuthenticationActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2466986703034345433, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2466986703034345432}]}
2018-12-19 14:07:09.150 15061-15098/com.solvednetworks.cptool D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2bcfa40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd25ec380)
2018-12-19 14:07:14.126 15061-15086/com.solvednetworks.cptool V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: If you are authenticating with Azure AD, can you make sure you are registering properly.  Link for your reference -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad.  Also, make sure that you nave defined a URL scheme correctly for you app.  Link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users#redirecturl.

Comment: You can also check the android sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android